# OSX: Dealing with a segfault for apps started using "open"

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am launching an app from a script using:

```
open /path/to/foo.app -F -g -W --args -foo bar
```

When the application crashes (in particular, it seg faults), the window sits open forever and the app does not exit. However, when I launch the app the old fashioned way

```
/path/to/foo.app/Contents/MacOSX/foo -foo bar
```

it simply exits and returns a nonzero error code to the script, which is what I want. How can I get this behaviour (exit on seg fault and return an error code) using the "open" syntax above? The motivation is to get access to OSX-specific options such as -F, -g, -W etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the -W option. From [open's man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html):

> -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.  Use
>            with the -n flag to allow open to function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment vari-
>            able.

This could be your issue.